# Import external library in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import

I'm trying to import in a project the library `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution`.

I wrote the following few lines for a project in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1. I'm sure there are few mistakes here and there (I'm new to Scala and I don't have previous Java experience either), so apologies for that. My issue is that Scala doesn't seem to import the library, I can't use the functions associate with it on the body of my object (i.e. `cumulativeProbability`).

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution
import scala.math._

// Compute statistical power given confidence level, significance level, sample sizes and means on the
// Normal distribution case
object test_math_lib {
  def main(n1: Int, n2: Int, significance: Double, mu1: Double, mu2: Double, alternative: String): Double = {
  if alternative = "two sided":
    val b = 0.50 // just for the sake of testing
    val x = new (1 - cumulativeProbability(b))
  }
}
```

This is just a draft, I'm just writing the function myself and I don't have any prior experience both with Java and Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call the method `cumulativeProbability` on an instance of class `NormalDistribution`.

So, you will first have to create a `NormalDistribution` object, and then call the method on that object. Something like this:

```
val distr = new NormalDistribution()
val prob = distr.cumulativeProbability(b)
```

I don't know what you mean by the `new` in this line:

```
val x = new (1 - cumulativeProbability(b))
```

but that's not valid syntax. You use the `new` operator to create a new object - I don't know what your intention was here.

Comment: Hi Jesper. I still have NormalDistribution() and cumulativeProbability(b) in a red font. Should I download on my hard drive something to use that external library? my current code is: 

import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution
import scala.math._

object test_lib {
  def main(n1: Int, n2: Int, significance: Double, mu1: Double, mu2: Double, alternative: String): Double = {
    if (alternative == "two sided") {

      val b = 0.50 // just for the sake of testing
      val distr = new NormalDistribution()
      val cum_prob = distr.cumulativeProbability(b)

    }
  }
}

Comment: Yes, you should [download](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi) the JAR file and make it available in your project.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that the dependency is available to the project.

If for example your project is sbt-based, see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html, if you use maven the story is pretty much the same.
Once you update your project definition, you need to recreate project files for your IntelliJ, I think you can use sbt-idea for sbt, and finally reimport the project. The support for maven should be integrated instead.

If you created your project directly in IntelliJ without relying on these two then you need to add the jar dependency to your build path, see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Dependencies+Management+%28Build+Path%29.

If the configuration is correct then you will see no red squiggle under the import statement for the library.

About the snippet, you should check what can you actually do with `NormalDistribution` by checking the Javadoc for it, I read you have some different constructors, by which you can configure your instance, for example setting a random generator explicitly.
When you get the instance you can call all of the public instance methods on it.