# scala packages import error in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scala-java-interop

I am trying to compile scala code in IntelliJ IDEA (community 2019.2) on MacBook. My scala version: 2.13.0.

In the code:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

is greyed out and "JavaConverters._" is crossed-out.

and

```
 import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

the "JavaConversions._" is marked as RED, which means that it cannot be resolved.

I also tried

```
   import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters
```

which is also greyed out (which means it is not used)

But, I can do the same things in command line.

Are there something I missed in IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: It is unused, because you missed the `._` at the end. You want to import all the (implicit) things from `CollectionConverters`.

Comment: I used "import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._" but it is greyed out (still not in used) in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 4):

In repl behavior is the same

```
[IJ]sbt:scala213demo1> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.13.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_162).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
                               ^
       error: object JavaConversions is not a member of package collection

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
```

If behavior in repl is different for you then you start repl with different version of scala.

In 2.13 correct is

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
```

`scala.collection.JavaConverters._` is deprecated, `scala.collection.JavaConversions` was deprecated even in 2.12 and now unavailable.

Comment: I used "import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._" but it is greyed out (still not in used) in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @user3448011 Who cares about IntelliJ highlighting, important is whether code compiles.

Comment: No, it does not compile. Example errors: toList is not a member of java.util.list.

Comment: @user3448011 Why `.toList`? It should be `.asScala` https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/AsScalaExtensions.scala

Comment: @user3448011 or `.asScala.toList`

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, it shows that "java.util.List<java.lang.Double> as no member of asScala".

Answer (score 0):

The first part of this [Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29364697/1655863) helped me to give me some sense of the `sbt` dependency management.  With that construct, I looked at the `Build` tab and read through the error messages about errors downloading the dependencies by the `sbt`.  From that error message I learned that I have included the Scala version as part of the package name:

**Incorrect example:**  `azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12`

**Corrected example:**  `azure-eventhubs-spark`

This is because the `build.sbt` file contains a variable definition called `ThisBuild/scalaVersion := "2.12.15"` that it knows how to parse and append the specific Scala version to the package name.

Using the above example in the context of `LibraryDepdencies`, here is how it looks for 1 dependency library:

**Incorrect example:**
`"com.microsoft.azure" %% "azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12" % "2.3.21" % "provided"`

**Corrected example:**
`"com.microsoft.azure" %% "azure-eventhubs-spark" % "2.3.21" % "provided"`

Once your `build.sbt` file is updated using the correct package name reference, inside the `Build` tab, right click on your project and select `Reload sbt Project`.  It will reload the updated `build.sbt` file definition and reattempt to download the dependency package(s) for you and resolve the red fonts in your editor that the class is not able to resolve error.